# java + can we miss signals using wait and notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

extract from this [semaphore tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html) says:

> Using a semaphore like this you can avoid **missed signals**. You will call take() instead of notify() and release() instead of wait(). If the call to take() happens before the call to release() the thread calling release() will still know that take() was called, because the signal is stored internally in the signal variable. This is not the case with wait() and notify().

Can't we avoid the missed signals using wait and notify alone ?

Comment: No, for example, if `notify()` was called _before_ `wait()`

Answer (score 3):

With wait and notify you should always

- wait based on a condition
- notify which changes the state checked by the wait.

Note: it is possible for wait() to wake spuriously so you cannot assume a notify() was called.

> Can't we avoid the missed signals using wait and notify alone ?

No, you never could which is why it was always assumed it would be associated with a state change.

e.g.  A common interview question is to write a simple blocking Queue.

```
// a simple blocking queue using an AtomicReference
final Object lock = new Object();
final E eRef = null;

public void push(E e) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(eRef != null)
             lock.wait();
        eRef = e;
        lock.notifyAll();
     }
}

public E take() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(eRef == null)
            lock.wait();
        E e = eRef;
        eRef = null;
        lock.notifyAll();
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Can you show some example code to make it more clear Peter?

Answer (score 3):

A missed signal can occur when you have two threads where one calls `notify()` before the other calls `wait()`. The only way to avoid this happening is to have some kind of barrier that makes the second thread wait until the first thread has called `notify()` - one mechanism that can be used to create this barrier is a semaphore :)